# Inconsistent type in golang, cannot use <Type> as <Type>

Tags: go, goland

I am writing an application in Go that uses a Logger object type.

In it I use another application that uses the same logger object type:

App1:

```
import "gitlab.sio.com/go/zlog"

var logger = zlog.New(append(opts,
    zlog.App(c.Name, typ, version),
    zlog.Env(c.Environment),
)...)
....
router.GET("/get", GetHandler(logger))
....
func GetHandler(logger *zlog.Logger){
    ....
    mdl, _ := security.New(*logger)
    ....
}
```

App2(security.New from security lib):

```
package security

import "gitlab.sio.com/go/zlog"

Middleware struct {
    log             zlog.Logger
}

func New(log zlog.Logger){
...
mdw := Middleware{}
mdw.log = log
}
```

The error what I'm getting at line

> mdl, _ := security.New(*logger)

is:

> cannot use *logger (type "gitlab.sio.com/go/furtif/vendor/gitlab.sio.com/go/zlog".Logger) as type "gitlab.sio.com/go/security/vendor/gitlab.sio.com/go/zlog".Logger in argument to security.New

Comment: Read the message carefully: These are different types. One is from package `.../furtif/vendor...`, the other from `.../security/vendor/...`. Fix your vendoring.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to the same library imported in two different vendor folders.
If you are trying to use the application 2 only as a library, removing the vendor folder in the application 2 will solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your import statements to properly point the import types from where they should belong to. Read the error message.

Comment: It's not the import statements at issue. It's that there are two separately-vendored copies of the same library in the GOPATH - seems like they've imported a library that uses vendoring which is, as always, a Bad Thing™.

Answer (score -1):

This error happened to me because I had a type declared more than once across the same package.